# php extract multiple sections of text from string

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm trying to extract the text in the following way:

```
$subname = "subarray({value=subarray({0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}, EXCEL*48, 1)";            
preg_match('#\{(.*?)\}#',$subname, $match,  PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($match[1][1]);
$matchs = substr( $subname, 0, $match[1][1]);
print_r($matchs);
```

I would like to obtain the following text from $subname

1. 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48
2. EXCEL
3. *48

I'm struggling with the 2nd bit (getting the EXCEL word). I wonder whether it is possible to get preg_match to give me the rest of the string?

Comment: Capture it with [`'#\{(.*?)},\s*(\p{L}+)(\*\d+)#'`](https://regex101.com/r/w08NtY/1)

Comment: Yes it is possible, just change `#\{(.*?)\}#` to `#\{(.*?), (EXCEL)(\*48)\}#`. Now, if the word can be something else please describe your pattern, what could be there, and show what have you tried to capture the missing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'#\{([\s\d.,]*)},\s*(\p{L}+)(\*\d+)#'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w08NtY/2).

*Details*:

- `\{`  - a `{`
- `([\s\d.,]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ whitespaces, digits, commas and dots
- `}` -  a literal `}`
- `,`  - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\p{L}+)` - Group 2: one or more letters
- `(\*\d+)` - Group 3: a `*` and 1+ digits.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/pArCfI) below.

```
$subname = "subarray({value=subarray({0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}, EXCEL*48, 1)";            
$res = array();
if (preg_match('#\{([\s\d.,]*)},\s*(\p{L}+)(\*\d+)#',$subname, $match)) {
    $res = explode(", ", $match[1]);
    array_push($res, $match[2]);
    array_push($res, $match[3]);
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Wiktor, this is amazing, I didn't know preg_match could do all this!